# Any screen recorders specifically for CLIs?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, screen-recorder

I want to record videos specifically on Ubuntu's CLI and recordmydesktop has been giving me inaccurate window dimensions and low frame rates for following my typing.

Ideally, I'd like to record on server editions (without a GUI) but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`script` is commonly used for this purpose, although it does not output video files – instead `scriptreplay` must be used.

```
$ script --timing=foo.tm foo
Script started, file is foo
$
...do stuff...
$ exit
Script done, file is foo
$ scriptreplay foo.tm foo
```

Another similar tool is [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en) along with [IPBT](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/ipbt/).